# Do you know any Teradata MVC Tools?

Tags: teradata

Can you recommend me any multi value compression tools for Teradata aside from Atana Suite and Prise Tools?

Comment: What's wrong with the tools you mentioned? And why can't you use them?

Comment: I'm using the trial version and output doesn't show (Atana) whilst Prise seems really limited in trial version as well that I can't tell how much good it does

Comment: Database can provide you biased values for columns from statistics. Those can be used to help you decide what to compress. Can it be automated? Yes, if you want to take the time to shred XML, build DDL in code, and place the necessary guard rails around it.

Answer (score 0):

Nexus, a query-editor by Coffin Datawarehousing, also has a module called SmartCompress. A bit limited, you cannot submit batch requests for compressing multible tables, but in general it does the job. You have to license both Nexus and SmartCompress but it is not expensive if you just buy one set of licenses for the admins.